# MATLAB extract field from struct in a vector array

Tags: matlab, struct

I got the following Problem: I got a struct Array and want to extract one field from that struct in a vector.

The struct has 5 fields, one which is called "name". How can I get These in a vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [the `extractfield` method](http://se.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/extractfield.html):

```
yourNameFieldsAsArray = extractfield(yourStruct, 'name')
```

Where `yourNameFieldsAsArray` will be a cell array if the `name` field holds e.g. character/string values, or a regular value array if `name` field just hold, say, integers.

Comment: [Solution does not require Mapping Toolbox](HTTP://stackoverflow.com/a/35456196/4953146)

Answer (score 7):

The answer by dfri works but requires MATLAB Mapping Toolbox. You can use 
`{yourStruct.name}` to get them as a cell array or `[yourStruct.name]` to get them as an array:

```
>> A(1).name='a'; 
>> A(2).name='b';
>> A(3).name='c';
>> {A.name}
ans = 
    'a'    'b'    'c'
```

or,

```
>> A(1).num=10;
>> A(2).num=5;
>> A(3).num=25;
>> [A.num]
ans =
    10     5    25
```