# In MATLAB: How should nested fields of a struct be converted to a cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

In MATLAB, I would like to extract a nested field for each index of a 1 x n struct (a nonscalar struct) and receive the output as a 1 x n cell array.  As a simple example, suppose I start with the following struct s:

```
s(1).f1.fa = 'foo';
s(2).f1.fa = 'yedd';
s(1).f1.fb = 'raf';
s(2).f1.fb = 'da';
s(1).f2 = 'bok';
s(2).f2 = 'kemb';
```

I can produce my desired 1 x 2 cell array c using a for-loop:

```
n = length(s);
c = cell(1,n);
for k = 1:n
    c{k} = s(k).f1.fa;
end
```

If I wanted to do analogously for a *non-nested* field, for example f2, then I could "vectorize" the operation (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454907/matlab-extract-field-from-struct-in-a-vector-array)), writing simply:

```
c = {s.f2};
```

However the same approach does not appear to work for nested fields.  What then are possible ways to vectorize the above for-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot really vectorize it. The problem is that Matlab does not allow most forms of nested indexing, including `[].`.

The most concise / readable option would be to concatenate `s.f1` results in a structure array using `[...]`, and then index into the new structure array with a separate call:

```
x = [s.f1]; c = {x.fa};
```

If you have a Mapping Toolbox, you could use [extractfield](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/extractfield.html) to perform the second indexing in one expression:

```
c = extractfield([s.f1], 'fa');
```

Alternatively you could write a one-liner using `arrayfun` - here's a couple of options:

```
c = arrayfun(@(x) x.f1.fa, s, 'uni', false);
c = arrayfun(@(x) x.fa, [s.f1], 'uni', false);
```

Note that `arrayfun` and similar functions are generally slower than explicit `for` loops. So if the performance is critical, time / profile your code, before making a decision to get rid of the loop.