# Export variables from Matlab struct to R

Tags: r, matlab

I think this won't be very complex, but I'm unable to figure this out.

I have in Matlab a `17x1 struct` object with 6 fields, named `photolist`. I only want to export the `name` field , to use in R.

`photolist.name` gives me the list I need, but when I want to store it in a variable:

```
name = photolist.name
```

I only get the first value, same for

```
name = getfield(photo_list, 'name')
```

and while

```
name = [photolist.name]
```

gives me all values, it does so in one long string without spaces.

using

```
save('temp.mat', 'photolist')
```

gives me something I can import to R, but then I need to go multiple nested layers deep to get the values I need, which is a workaround but not very satisfying.

How do i save just the .name fields to a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454907/matlab-extract-field-from-struct-in-a-vector-array?rq=1)

```
names = extractfield(photolist, 'name')
```

And another way to get the same result is:

```
names = {photolist.name}
```